# Creating, storing and using TIME values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am not new to SQL, but recently created a table that holds a column defined as `TIME`. For some reason I can't get this field to take the value just under 12 AM (`23:59:99.999`). My simplified TSQL is below.

```
DECLARE @Time TIME = '23:59:99.99999'
UPDATE tblProjectSLA
SET colSLATime = @Time
WHERE SLAID IN ( 22, 24)
```

I get the following ERROR:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>  
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I was able set the time value to the lowest possible time 'resolution' and it updated the field successfully.

```
DECLARE @Time DATETIME = '23:59'
```

Here is the result as it appears in SQL mgr when I query it:

```
colSLATime
23:59:00.0000000
```

I also tried CASTing the string value to TIME... same error:

```
DECLARE @Time TIME = CAST('23:59:99.99999' AS TIME)
```

What I find odd is that the table is defined for a precision of 16 and scale of 7, shouldn't I be able to use something close to the value saved in the table?

Here is how the column colSLATime is defined... (using the sp_help command and transposed to read easier)

```
Column_name           colSLATime
Type                  time
Computed              no
Length                5
Prec                  16
Scale                 7
Nullable              yes
TrimTrailingBlanks    (n/a)
FixedLenNullInSource  (n/a)
Collation             NULL
```

If someone could point me to a simple discussion on the ins & outs of using the TIME data type. Or should I scrap and just use a VARCHAR field and CAST at run time (guessing not).

[REFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
time (Transact-SQL)
SQL Server 2008 R2
Range      00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try using:

```
23:59:59.99999
------^ this digit is pretty important!
```

Instead of

```
23:59:99.99999
------^
```

There is no such thing as 99 seconds in a minute!

Comment: Jeeze! ...can't see the forest thru the trees! DECLARE @Time TIME = '23:59:59.9999999' worked!
Thanks for setting me straight!